# Azure Database Large Table Group By Performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, azure

I'm looking for design and/or index recommendations for the problem listed below.

I have a couple of denormalized tables in an Azure S1 Standard (20 DTU) database. One of those tables has ~20 columns and a million rows. My application requirements need me to support sub-second (or at least close to it) querying of this table by any combination of columns in my WHERE clause, as well as sub-second (or at least close to it) querying of DISTINCT values in each column.

In order to picture the use case behind this, here is an example. Imagine you were using an HR application that allowed you to search for employees and view employee information. The employee table might have 5 columns and millions of rows. The application allows you to filter by any column, and provides an interface to allow this. Therefore, the underlying SQL queries that must be made are:

- A *GROUP BY* (or *DISTINCT*) query for each column, which provides the interface with the available filter options
- A general employee search query, that filters all rows by any combination of filters

In order to solve performance issues on the first set of queries, I've implemented the following:

1. Index columns with a large variety of values
2. Full-Text index columns that require string matching (So *CONTAINS* querying instead of *LIKE*)
3. Do not index columns with a small variety of values

In order to solve the performance issues on the second query, I've implemented the following:

1. Forcing the front end to use pagination, implemented using `SELECT * FROM table OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT n ROWS ONLY`, and ensuring the order by column is indexed

Locally, this seemed to work fine. Unfortunately, and Azure Standard database doesn't have the same performance as my local machine, and I'm seeing issues. Specifically, the columns I am not indexing (the ones with a very small set of distinct values) are taking 30+ seconds to query for. Additionally, while the paging is initially very quick, the query takes longer and longer the higher and higher I increase the offset.

So I have two targeted questions, but any other advice or design suggestions would be most welcome:

1. How bad is it to index every column in the table? Know that the table does need to be updated, but the columns that I update won't actually be part of any filters or WHERE clauses. Will the indexes still need to be rebuilt on update? You can also safely assume that the table will not see any inserts/deletes, except for once a month where the entire table is truncated and rebuilt from scratch
2. In regards to the paging getting slower and slower the deeper I get, I've read this is expected, but the performance becomes unacceptable at a certain point. Outside of making my clustered column the sort by column, are there any other suggestions to get this working?

Thanks,
-Tim